# How to best retrieve non-duplicate results from non-normalized data?

Tags: mysql

I'm working from a dump of some *DISASTER* legacy-data which effectively has **zero** data normalization. Just about ALL fields were manually keyed.  There were no constraints. Data relationships are weak and unstable (based on text-matches of mutable data).

*NOTE: I added `id` fields when I imported the data from the legacy CSV exports.  You'll see ID's in my SQL, but they were not part of the original data.  They are useless unless self-referencing.*

**GOAL**
Our goal is to get a list of "active" customers  (companies which we've had any quote or sale interaction with in the last few years) for import into our new/modern program.

I am prioritizing Bill-To address records.  If an active-company has one, then that's the address row I want. (if a company has several, then we're left just picking one arbitrarily.)  If an active-company does not have a "billing" address specified, then again, we're left to just arbitrarily grab one from what's there.
The result set should contain only one single row for a given company name.

*NOTE: `addresses.description` could be **ANYTHING**; like "Bill To" or "NY" or "Main St" or "shipto" or "Bill/Ship" or ...*

**SOURCE**
The source table is `addresses` which contains as many rows for a given company as addresses they've ever had since the dawn of time ... including drop-ship-to addresses.
There are no company_id's. The index is on company names.  Most companies have multiple rows in the addresses table, and some have 10, 20, or more entries.

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**
My SQL skills are quite novice and super rusty.  But I did ultimately achieve the desired results.
That being said, my solution is ***exceedingly*** kludgy!  Since this data is going to have to be re-exported several times throughout the testing and  migration phases, I'd *really* like to save a more streamlined (easily reusable) SQL.

Here's what I've come to so far:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE active_billto_companies 
(id INT PRIMARY KEY, company varchar(72));

INSERT INTO active_billto_companies (id, company)
SELECT MIN(active.id), active.company 
FROM(
    SELECT
        addr.id,
        addr.company,
        addr.description
    FROM addresses addr
    WHERE addr.company IN
        (SELECT DISTINCT s.company FROM sales s WHERE s.`datetime` > '2019-01-01 00:00:00')
    OR addr.company IN
        (SELECT DISTINCT q.company FROM quotes q WHERE q.`datetime` > '2019-01-01 00:00:00')
    OR addr.company IN
        (SELECT DISTINCT i.company FROM invoices i WHERE i.`datetime` > '2019-01-01 00:00:00')
    ORDER BY addr.id
) AS active
WHERE active.description LIKE '%bill%'
GROUP BY active.company;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE active_other_companies 
(id INT PRIMARY KEY, company varchar(72));

INSERT INTO active_other_companies (id, company)
SELECT MIN(active.id), active.company 
FROM(
    SELECT
        addr.id,
        addr.company,
        addr.description
    FROM addresses addr
    WHERE addr.company IN
        (SELECT DISTINCT s.company FROM sales s WHERE s.`datetime` > '2019-01-01 00:00:00')
    OR addr.company IN
        (SELECT DISTINCT q.company FROM quotes q WHERE q.`datetime` > '2019-01-01 00:00:00')
    OR addr.company IN
        (SELECT DISTINCT i.company FROM invoices i WHERE i.`datetime` > '2019-01-01 00:00:00')
    ORDER BY addr.id
) AS active
LEFT JOIN active_billto_companies b
    ON active.company = b.company
WHERE active.description NOT LIKE '%bill%'
AND b.company IS NULL
GROUP BY active.company;

SELECT
    a.id AS custno,
    LEFT (a.company, 30) AS name,
    a.line_1 AS addr1,
    a.line_2 AS addr2,
    a.line_3 AS addr3,
    a.city,
    a.state,
    a.postal_code AS zipcd,
    a.country AS countrycd,
    a.description
FROM addresses a
RIGHT JOIN active_billto_companies b
    ON a.id = b.id
UNION
SELECT
    a.id AS custno,
    LEFT (a.company, 30) AS name,
    a.line_1 AS addr1,
    a.line_2 AS addr2,
    a.line_3 AS addr3,
    a.city,
    a.state,
    a.postal_code AS zipcd,
    a.country AS countrycd,
    a.description
FROM addresses a
RIGHT JOIN active_other_companies o
    ON a.id = o.id;
```

What are some things I could do to achieve this more succinctly?

Comment: can you share some sample rows and field types for the tables you use in this query?